# Chaining array of AnyPublishers

Tags: swift, combine

I'm wondering if there is a way to chain **array of publishers** similar to how we chain publishers with regular `flatMap`

Let's say I have three publishers: **publisher1, publisher2, publisher3** all of them **have the same Output, Failure types**. For example, each of them is `AnyPublisher<String, Never>` and emits a single String value. The only role of each publisher is to fetch its own value and emits previous value joined with its own.

I'm looking for same effect as from the following pseudo code:

```
let pipe = publisher1(value: "")
      .flatMap { publisher2(value: $0) }
      .flatMap { publisher3(value: $0) }
```

Execution flow:

> publisher1 (fetches "A") -> publisher2 (fetches "B") -> publisher3 (fetches "C") -> "ABC"

I would like to reproduce the same flow for the array with unknown count of publishers **n** `([AnyPublisher<String, Never>])`

> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> ... -> n

I'll appreciate any tips, thanks! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "chain"? Chaining as if with `pub1.flatMap { pub2 }` means that for every value emitted by `pub1`, create a `pub2` to emit values. If you mean that first `pub1` should emit all its values and complete, then `pub2`, and so on, then you should use `pub1.append(pub2)` as in Joakim's answer. But you need to clarify first what you want. Remember that a publisher could be a single-shot publisher, or could emit N values, or indefinitely, or never emit anything.

Comment: I've updated the original question. I hope this will clarify the case a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, let's clarify your question. Based on your description of wanting to create a chain of `flatMap`-ed publishers, what you must have is an array of closures - not publishers - each returning an `AnyPublisher<String, Never>` publisher given a `String` parameter.

```
let pubs: [(String) -> AnyPublisher<String, Never>] = [
    publisher1, publisher2, publisher3 
]
```

To chain them, you could use a `reduce` method of the array by starting with a `Just` publisher to emit the initial parameter:

```
let pipe = pubs.reduce(Just("").eraseToAnyPublisher()) { acc, next in
   acc.flatMap { next($0) }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you should be able to use `append` on your publishers

```
let pub1: AnyPublisher<String, Never> = ["A1", "B1", "C1"].publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
let pub2: AnyPublisher<String, Never> = ["A2", "B2", "C2"].publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
let pub3: AnyPublisher<String, Never> = ["A3", "B3", "C3"].publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()


_ = pub1.append(pub2.append(pub3))
    .sink(receiveValue: { value in
        print(value)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to `zip` the publishers together, and them combine the latest values:

```swift
let publisher1 = ["A"].publisher
let publisher2 = ["B"].publisher
let publisher3 = ["C"].publisher

_ = publisher1.zip(publisher2, publisher3)
    .map { $0+$1+$2 }
    .sink(receiveValue: { print("Combined: \($0)") })

/// prints ABC
```

Or, if you have a variable size number of publishers, you can use `MergeMany` and `reduce`:

```swift
// same result: ABC
_ = Publishers.MergeMany([publisher1, publisher2, publisher3])
    .reduce("") { $0 + $1 }
    .sink(receiveValue: { print("Combined: \($0)") })
```

You can go even further, and write your own publisher, if you think you'll be needing this functionality in multiple places:

```swift
extension Publishers {
    /// works also with arrays, or any other range replaceable collection
    struct ConcatenateOutputs<Upstream: Publisher> : Publisher where Upstream.Output: RangeReplaceableCollection {
        typealias Output = Upstream.Output
        typealias Failure = Upstream.Failure
        
        private let reducer: AnyPublisher<Upstream.Output, Failure>
                
        init(_ publishers: Upstream...) {
            self.init(publishers)
        }
        
        init<S: Swift.Sequence>(_ publishers: S) where S.Element == Upstream {
            reducer = MergeMany(publishers)
                .reduce(Output.init()) { $0 + $1 }
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        
        func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input {
            reducer.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
        }
    }
}

extension Sequence where Element: Publisher, Element.Output: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var concatenateOutputs: Publishers.ConcatenateOutputs<Element> { .init(self) }
}

// same output
_ = Publishers.ConcatenateOutputs([publisher1, publisher2, publisher3])
    .sink(receiveValue: { print("Combined: \($0)") })

// the variadic initializer works the same
_ = Publishers.ConcatenateOutputs(publisher1, publisher2, publisher3)
    .sink(receiveValue: { print("Combined: \($0)") })

// the less verbose construct
_ = [publisher1, publisher2, publisher3].concatenateOutputs
    .sink(receiveValue: { print("Combined: \($0)") })
```